# unordered_map with iterators as keys, cast iterator to long long?

Tags: c++11, casting, hashmap, iterator, std

Unfortunatly this:

```
unordered_map<list<int>::iterator, int> foo;
```

does not work, the compiler says: error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

There seems to be a hash for 64 bit integers though, so is it save to use

```
unordered_map<long long, int> foo;
```

instead and simply cast the iterators to `long long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is, in general, not possible. While *pointers* can be cast to and from integer types (more on that later), iterators aren't necessarily pointers and so this cast isn't necessarily allowed. For example, consider something like an `istream_iterator`, which wraps a stream object. It's unclear what it would mean to cast this to or from a `long long`. If you're trying to solve the problem this way, you may need to change your approach.

As a note - the type `long long` is not actually required to be big enough to hold a pointer that's been converted to an integer. The special types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are guaranteed to be big enough to store a pointer, so you might want to start using those types instead. You still can't cast list iterators to these types, though.

Comment: How about using the address of the object the iterator is pointing at? Maybe i could  use that as a key?

Comment: That should work, provided that you don't then need to treat the pointer like an iterator. Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do? You may want to post a separate question describing your objective, since I suspect you may be missing a much cleaner way of solving this problem.

Comment: I want to traverse a graph of heavy objects so i have a vector of iterators to those objects but i need the inverse mapping too for breadth/depth first search. There are probably efficient graph libraries but i need not that much more than this traversal function.

Comment: I would recommend asking this as a separate question, describing in more detail what you're trying to do and how you're currently going about solving it. That would give your question more visibility and might let people propose better ways of accomplishing your goal.